# How to handle huge output displayed within 30 minutes before expecting prompt with pexpect

Tags: python, python-2.7, pexpect

I am trying to write a script with `pexpect` where I need to take huge output within 30 minutes before expecting the prompt.

```
child.sendline('abc')
child.expect('.*:abc.*')

child.sendline('test')
# child.timeout=1500
# There will be huge output displayed for 30 minutes here
child.expect('.*:abc.*', timeout=1500)
status = child.after
print status
```

Tried keeping `child.timeout`, but dint help.
Tried passing timeout with `child.expect`, but dint help.

Is there any way I can expect some prompt when output is huge and time required to reach to the prompt is around 30 minutes?

Comment: When I was young, I used *expect* (or *pexpect*) to connect to remote machines (S.A.). The `timeout` arg  was enough (and implicit).    What is the *pexpect* version that you use (*pexpect* is able to handle unhandable 
 timestamps)?

Comment: This is the version: pexpect==4.2.1

Comment: What do you exactly mean by *didn't help*? How didn't it work?

Comment: It timesout way before 1500 seconds and the error is: `<class 'pexpect.exceptions.EOF'>: End Of File (EOF). Exception style platform.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EOF exception means that your child process exited before your command timed out. To handle this case you can provide a list of expectations and handle the logic for each of them separately

```
result = child.expect(['.*:abc.*', pexpect.TIMEOUT, pexpect.EOF], timeout=1500)
if result == 1:
    # code to handle case where the expected string .*:abc.* was caught
if result == 2:
    # code to handle timeout exception
if result == 3:
    # code to handle EOF exception
```